# How to determinate position of a point with triangulation

Tags: geometry, sensors, wireless, triangulation

I am working on project of localization wireless sensors network. I am using triangulation method to estimate position of a wireless sensors, where I have two sensors its position is known :

> A(x1,Y1)
>
> and B(X2,Y2)
>
> and the point that I want to locate is c(x,y)

and I have the distances between those points :

> AB, AC & BC

How can I do that with triangulation ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation

Comment: i followed your link but i want a simple example to fond out how to determinate C(X,Y) coordinate of C

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it helps me to visualize the problem. First of, make sure that `AB < AC + BC`, because [that would look like this](http://s7.postimg.org/3v30ck40r/triangulation_1.jpg).

Second, you would need to find the [intersections of AC and BC](http://s12.postimg.org/js56b5rrh/triangulation_2.jpg).

Hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score 4):

Put

```
a := dist(B,C), b := dist(A,C).
A := (a1,a2), B := (b1,b2), C := (x,y).
```

We have

```
(x - a1)^2 + (y - a2)^2 = b^2           eq (1)
(x - b1)^2 + (y - b2)^2 = a^2
```

Thus:

```
x^2 -2(a1)x + (a1)^2 + y^2 -2(a2)y + (a2)^2 = b^2
x^2 -2(b1)x + (b1)^2 + y^2 -2(b2)y + (b2)^2 = a^2
```

Now subtract:

```
(2(b1) - 2(a1))x + (a1)^2 - (b1)^2 + 2((b2) - (a2))y + (a2)^2 - (b2)^2
    = b^2 - a^2
```

Solve for `y`:

```
y = u + vx                              eq (2)
```

where:

```
u := ((a1)^2 + (a2)^2 - ((b1)^2 + (b2)^2) + a^2 - b^2)/(2((a2) - (b2)))
v := (2((b1) - (a1)))/(2((a2) - (b2)))
```

Replace `y` with `u + vx` in eq 1 above:

```
(x - a1)^2 + (u + vx - a2)^2 = b^2 

rx^2 + sx + t = 0
```

where:

```
r := 1 + v^2
s := -2(a1) + 2uv - 2v(a2)
t := (a1)^2 + (uˆ2) - 2u(a2) + (a2)^2 - b^2
```

Solve for `x`

```
x = (-s +/- sqrt(s^2 - 4rt))/(2r)
```

From eq 2:

```
y = u + vx.
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH**

Let `a := dist(B,C)` and `b := dist(A,C)` as above and put `c := dist(A,B).` Let `theta` be the angle `BAC`, as depicted below.

[image]

We have

```
cos(theta) = (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)/(2bc)    eq (3)
```

Then we can derive `h` and `c1` as

```
h := b * sin(theta) = b * sqrt(1 - cost(theta)^2).
c1 := b * cos(theta)
```

So,

```
D := (d1, d2) = (B - A) * c1 / c + A    eq (4)
```

where

```
d1 := (b1 - a1)*c1/c + a1
d2 := (b2 - a2)*c1/c + a2
```

Now we can use the fact that `C` is at distance `h` on the perpendicular to `AB` intersecting at `D`:

```
C := (d1, d2) +/- ((a2 - b2)*h/c, (b1 - a1)*h/c)
```

where `+/-` stands for the two possibilities of `C` being above or below the line `AC`.

or

```
C = (x, y)
```

where

```
x := d1 +/- (a2 - b2)*h/c
y := d2 +/- (b1 - a1)*h/c
```

---

**Example**

```
A = (2,3) - B = (5,4) - a = sqrt(5) - b = sqrt(5)
```

Compute `c`:

```
c := dist(A,B) = 3.16227766016838.
```

From eq (3)

```
cos(theta) = 0.70710678118655
theta := 0.78539816339745 radians
```

Compute `h` and `c1`:

```
h := b * sin(theta) = 1.58113883008419.
c1 := b * cos(theta) = 1.58113883008419.
```

From eq (4):

```
D = (3.5,3.5)
```

Now compute `C`:

```
C = ((a2 - b2)) * h / c , (b1 - a1) * h / c) + D
  = (-0.5,1.5) + (3.5,3.5)
  = (3,5)
```

Verify:

```
dist(A,C) = dist((2,3),(3,5)) = sqrt(1ˆ2 + 2^2) = b (OK)
dist(B,C) = dist((5,4),(3,5)) = sqrt(2^2 + 1^2) = a (OK)
```

Comment: This is probably not the most elegant set of equations. However, it will hopefully let you move on with your project.

Comment: if there are any other method that helps to determinate the position of unknown points?

Comment: The equations would be simpler if you translate all the points to, say, `A` by subtracting `A` from itself and `B`, because that way you get rid of `a1` and `a2` (which become both `0`). So you can solve the problem for this simpler case  (which consists in rewriting the equations for `a1 = a2 = 0`) and then add `A` back to the solution to get the actual coordinates of `C` as `(x+a1, y+a2).`

Comment: i make some examples but the results didn't match, is the results of this algorithm is approximate or exact? could you please give me the source of this algorithm so i can use it as reference, thank you

Comment: in the equation  x = (-s +/- sqrt(s^2 - 4rt))/(2r)  [s +/-] it means s+ or s- ?

Comment: Yes, it is plus/minus sign because both are solutions. One solution is for the point above the AB line and the other one below it. Remember that quadratic equations have two solutions in general.

Comment: can you please give me the source of this algorithm to use it in my reference, thank you

Comment: @kamalHadjHafsi It is just the intersection of two circles.

Comment: if there any way to determinate those coordinates with angules? and if there is how to do that?

Comment: i mean the same conditions two points are known position and distance with the point that we want to locate but with angles?

Comment: @kamalHadjHafsi Yes, sure. Once you find the solution `C = (x,y)` applying the formulas given in my answer, you can find the angles of the triangle `ABC`. For instance, the angle `theta` between lines `AC` and `AB` has a cosine `cos(theta)` that satisfies: `(x-a1)(b1-a1) + (y-a2)(b2-a2) = bc cos(theta)`, where `b` is the length of segment `AC` and `c` the length of `AB`.

Comment: but sir what if i have already the angle 'theta'  calculated using the equation       `cos(ABC)=(c)²+(b)²-(a)²/2*(c)(b)`   and reverse the operation to get the coordinate of `C(x,y)`and i have`b` the length of `AC` & `c` length of `AB` and finally `a` length of `BC`, i hope you can help me thank you very much for your attention

Comment: @kamalHadjHafsi Doesn't matter. The equations are general enough.

Comment: hello sir , when i tested those equations with many examples it didn't return a correct results or at least nearest results : the last example i tested is `A(2.3) B(5.4)  and C that we want to locate is (3.5) and C above AB and  AB=c=sqrt(10)=3.16  AC=b=sqrt(5)=2.23 BC=sqrt(5)=2.23 `    `cos(theta)=10+5-5/2*(2.23)*(3.16)=0.7`  `h=2.23 * sqrt(1 - (0.7)^2)=159.` & `c1=2.23 *0.7=1.56` so `d1=(5 - 2)*1.56/3.16=1.48`  and `d2=(4 - 3)*1.56/3.16=0.49` so in final ` X=1.48 + (3 - 4)*1.56/3.16=-0.02`  and  `Y= 0.49+ (5 - 2)*1.56/3.16= 1.63` C(-0.02,1.63) i hope i am wrog in some equation

Comment: @kamalHadjHafsi My mistake. I had forgotten to add A in eq (4). I've updated my answer.

Comment: can you please give me a simple example perhaps i where mistaken in some equation because even when i tried after your update the results steel wrong , thank you sir

Comment: @kamalHadjHafsi I've added an example.